# Limit accepted values based on another table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to create two tables `companies` and `locations` in MariaDB.

```
companies
+------------+-------------+--------------+
| company_id | location_id | company_name |
+------------+-------------+--------------+
|          1 |           2 | abc          |
|          2 |           9 | xyz          |
+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

.

```
locations
+-----+-------------+---------------+------------+
| key | location_id | location_name | company_id |
+-----+-------------+---------------+------------+
|   1 |           1 | London        |          1 |
|   2 |           2 | Hong Kong     |          1 |
|   3 |           3 | Berlin        |          1 |
|   4 |           7 | Hong Kong     |          2 |
|   5 |           2 | London        |          2 |
|   6 |           9 | NY            |          2 |
+-----+-------------+---------------+------------+
```

`location_id` `1`,`2` and `3` with `company_id` `1` are associated with `company` `abc` and `location_id` `7`,`2` and `9` with `company_id` `2`  are associated with `company` `xyz`. Therefore the `location_id` for `company` `abc` should only accept the values `1`, `2` and `3`. Similarly the `location_id` for `company` `xyz` should only accept the values `7`, `2` and `9`.  The `location_id`s are not unique by them self but the combination of `location_id` and `company_id` is. Is there any way I can setup these tables with `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` or similar to achieve this?

Comment: What you have described sounds more like a "business rule"? Foreign keys cannot help enforce that logic, as foreign keys are designed to maintain "referential integrity" between parent/child tables. There is no way to limit foreign key restrictions to specific ID's that way.

Comment: (continued) ... you might want to reconsider the design of the locations table, as there is trouble looming. Why are there two different id's for the London and Hong Kong names? Perhaps you can reduce the locations table to have two columns: a location_id and location_name, and then possibly have another city_locations (or a name to your liking) association table that has a two-column combination of location_id and company_id? If this makes sense? This should help ease the business logic mentioned previously.